# unexpected output from git diff --word-diff. Is it a bug?

Tags: git

The `--word-diff` option to `git diff` is very valuable because it tells you what changed within a line, but..

```
$ cat f_old
test case id=10
logged to journal

$ cat f_new
test case id=20
#logged to journal

$ git diff -U0 --word-diff --no-index -- f_old  f_new
diff --git a/f_old b/f_new
index 81f1112..807598e 100644
--- a/f_old
+++ b/f_new
@@ -1,2 +1,2 @@
test case [-id=10-]
[-logged-]{+id=20+}
{+#logged+} to journal
```

Isn't that messed up? Why mix up one line with the other? I would expect

```
@@ ... @@
test case [-id=10-]{+id=20+}
[-logged-]{+#logged} to journal
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The changed sequences include the internal white space, the newlines. `id=10<nl>logged` changed to `id=20<nl>#logged` and that's what Git showed you. If you want to shut off whitespace processing completely you can try `--word-diff-regex=.` in place of `--word-diff`.